# Append of lists in Python

Tags: list, python-2.7, append

A strange append of list in python.

Here I defined a class

```
class test:
    group = []
    def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = str(name)
```

Then I write those

```
test0 = test(0)
test1 = test(1)
test_list = [test0, test1]
```

I want to save `test1.name` into `test0.group`

```
test_list[0].group.append(test_list[1].name)
```

I print test0.group , it's ['1'] , everything is OK.
But while I want to save test0.name into test1.group

```
test_list[1].group.append(test_list[0].name)
```

Then I print `test1.group` , it's `['1','0']`. I don't know why it isn't `['0']`?
By the way, here I print `test0.group` , it's also the `['1','0']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the `group` variable is a variable shared by all instances of the class `test` and therefore `test0` and `test1` share the same group. When you do the first append i.e. `'1'` it is fine but when you do the second append you are appending to the same list and therefore it becomes `['1', '0']`. In fact, if you print `test0.group` as the last line of your code, you will see that it also is `['1', '0']` because they are the same variable. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but if you want separate groups then you should make them `self.group` instead and move them into the `__init__` method. If you can rephrase your question, I can maybe help you with what you are **actually** trying to achieve.

Comment: Your answer is short but very useful. I've solve the problem~

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in the class definition:

```
class test:
    group = []
    def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = str(name)
```

At this point, the `__init__` method does nothing and `self.name = str(name)` never gets called. You need to indent `self.name = str(name)` in order for it to be in `__init__`'s body. Try this:

```
class test:
    group = []
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = str(name)
```

Comment: anyway thanks , the indentation error is my mistake when edit the problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same problem discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040438/class-variables-is-shared-across-all-instances-in-python).

Surprisingly? when you define class, Python interpreter execute class field. And then if you create a new instance of the class, class field is not executed. So class field is executed once only when you define class. Like:

```
class someClass:
    someVar = 0        #<---This class field is executed once
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

OK. Now you defined class. Next you create new instance of the class. Like:

```
instance1 = someClass()
instance2 = someClass()
```

This will create new memory and copy data from `someClass`.
Now `instance1` and `instance2` do not share memory space. They have own independent memory space. So `instance1.someVar` and `instance2.someVar` has different memory space. But `0` in `instance1.someVar` and `0` in `instance2.someVar` are completely same object(`0` is on same memory space). You can ensure it doing like:

```
print id(instance1.someVar)==id(instance2.someVar)
```

So you can find `0` is completely same object.

This is not the only case when `someClass.someVar = 0`. Same thing will happen when you use `[]` replacement of `0`.

---

Back to your code. You can simply occur your problem doing like this:

```
class test:
    group = []
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = str(name)

test0 = test(0)
test1 = test(1)

test0.group.append(100)

print test0.group
print test1.group
#[100]
#[100]
#will be printed
```

This is because `test0.group` and `test1.group` point same object. Like:

```
+-----------+
|test0.group|------+
+-----------+      |
                   v
               +-------+
               |  []   |
               +-------+
                   ^
+-----------+      |
|test1.group|------+
+-----------+
```

When you executed `test0.group.append(100)`, it becomes like:

```
+-----------+
|test0.group|------+
+-----------+      |
                   v
               +-------+
               | [100] |
               +-------+
                   ^
+-----------+      |
|test1.group|------+
+-----------+
```

Also you can set another object. Like:

```
test1.group = "123"
```

Then `test1.group` becomes like:

```
+-----------+
|test0.group|------+
+-----------+      |
                   v
               +-------+
               | [100] |
               +-------+

+-----------+       +-----+
|test1.group|------>|"123"|
+-----------+       +-----+
```

Sorry for my bad English. I hope it helps. :)

Comment: thank you so mauch for your Patient to a new hand.  ^_^