# my deepcopy does not work in this situation

Tags: python, copy

As far as I know, copy.deepcopy copies objects which contained in target object.

But my code doesn't work in this situation.

```
import copy

class MyClass(object):
    list_value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

a = MyClass('a')
b = copy.deepcopy(a)

a.list_value[0] = 10

print a.list_value
print b.list_value
```

The output was saying `list_value` of `b` instance is same with `list_value` of `a`.

> [10, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> [10, 2, 3, 4, 5]

What I expected was that `list_value` of only `a` changes.

Is there any thing I missed about deepcopy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list_value` is a [class attribute](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) shared by all object instances of class `MyClass`. So even if you specify `a.list_value[0]`, the `list_value` is the same for `a` and `b`. It's better to change your constructor to add it as an attribute for a specific object instance:

```
 def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name
      self.list_value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Ahh... then, should I put only shared variables in a class field?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "shared by all instances"? Also, provide links to the documentation about this phenomenon.

Comment: @Flyte, @Juniorcompressor I changed code as `JuniorCompressor` said, and there is no problem now.

Comment: @Flyte: every single time something of class `MyClass` is made, it will have the **same** list `list_value`.  A change made to `list_value` through any of the objects will change `list_value` for all of them.  Here is a discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040438/class-variables-is-shared-across-all-instances-in-python

Comment: @Joel, According to the discussion, `list_value` of `MyClass` instance will work as shared attribute as long as there is no replacement operation about `list_value`?