# Python Unittest and object initialization

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, python-unittest

My Python version is 3.5.1

I have a simple code (tests.py):

```
import unittest

class SimpleObject(object):
    array = []

class SimpleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_first(self):
        simple_object = SimpleObject()
        simple_object.array.append(1)

        self.assertEqual(len(simple_object.array), 1)

    def test_second(self):
        simple_object = SimpleObject()
        simple_object.array.append(1)

        self.assertEqual(len(simple_object.array), 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

If I run it with command 'python tests.py' I will get the results:

```
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_second (__main__.SimpleTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 105, in test_second
    self.assertEqual(len(simple_object.array), 1)
AssertionError: 2 != 1

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.003s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Why it is happening? And how to fix it. I expect that each tests run will be independent (each test should pass), but it is not as we can see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The array is shared by all instances of the class. If you want the array to be unique to an instance you need to put it in the class initializer:

```
class SimpleObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = []
```

For more information take a look at this question: [class variables is shared across all instances in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11040438/7432)

Comment: Thank you. What a newbie mistake :) I will accept your answer in 9 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished directly in unittest if you prefer to use only 1 class. Implement the setUp class. setUp runs before any of the tests are run as the class is instantiated. It is similar to **init** but conforms to the unittest library. Note the opposite is tearDown which is executed at the end of the test class if you need to build and deprecate objects. Example:

```
class SimpleObject(unitest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # I run first
        self.array = []

    def some_test(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.array == [])
        <some test code here>

    def tearDown(self):
        # I run last
        self.array = []. # or whatever teardown code you need
```

enjoy!