# Appending an item to a element of a list, adds it to all of the elements in the list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

I have two Classes *Cars* and *CarCategory* and in the CarCategory there is a list of *Cars*. The classes are defined as below:

```
class Car:
    Name     = None
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.Name = name

class CarCategory:
    Category = None    
    lstCars = []
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.Cateogory = name
```

Then I defined a list of CarCategories as below:

```
lstCategories = []

tmpcat = CarCategory('SUV')
lstCategories.append(tmpcat)

tmpcat = CarCategory('MPV')
lstCategories.append(tmpcat)
```

Now, I am supposed to add list if cars into these categories, and I do it as bellow:

```
tmpCar = Car('X3')
lstCategories[0].lstCars.append(tmpCar)
```

The problem is that while doing this, the *tmpCar* is added to list of cars in both categories, i.e. it is added to both *lstCategories[0]* and *lstCategories[1]*.

I am using, Spyeder and Python 3.7.

PS: I know this might not be the best way, and it is better to have Category property in *Car* class, but I need to do it like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `lstCars` in category is static thus **shared by all instances**. You should make it instance-based not class-based, like below:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.Name = name # property of instance

class CarCategory:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.lstCars = [] # property of instance
        self.Category = name # property of instance

    # optionally you can add an `add` method to add cars to categories
    def add(self, car):
        self.lstCars.append(car) # append to THIS instance 
        return self # make it chainable

# now try
lstCategories = []

tmpcat = CarCategory('SUV')
lstCategories.append(tmpcat)

tmpcat = CarCategory('MPV')
lstCategories.append(tmpcat)

tmpCar = Car('X3')
# using `add method`
lstCategories[0].add(tmpCar)
print(lstCategories[0].lstCars)
print(lstCategories[1].lstCars)
```

[check online](https://repl.it/repls/DryTechnologicalHardware)

Comment: I am switching between different programming languges at the moment, and I had in mind that self, works as this in C/++/#.

Answer (score 0):

Concept explained and discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11040513/9863661).

Comment: sorry thats a typo in the question, I did append it in the list of cars, but the problem was as it is mentioned aboved

Answer (score 0):

[Basically I found this and used it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field)

```
import dataclasses 

@dataclasses.dataclass 
class Car:
    Name : str 

@dataclasses.dataclass
class CarCategory:
    Category : str
    lstCars: list = dataclasses.field(default_factory=list)
     

    
    def add(self, car):
        self.lstCars.append(car) 
        return self 


lstCategories = []

tmpcat = CarCategory('SUV')
lstCategories.append(tmpcat)


tmpcat = CarCategory('MPV')
lstCategories.append(tmpcat)

tmpCar = Car('X3')

# using `add method`
lstCategories[0].add(tmpCar)
print(lstCategories[0].lstCars)
print(lstCategories[1].lstCars)
```

gives,

```
[Car(Name='X3')]
[]

[Program finished]
```